# Shakespeare wrote "a great many" plays?

Tags: indefinite-article, quantifiers

How is "a great many" grammatical?Many being modified by great in this case is something I have never heard before. I would say "wrote a great number of plays" or "wrote a lot of plays", maybe even "wrote very (adverb) many plays" although this is already something that I would look to avoid but "a great many plays" sounds very strange.

Comment: It's an idiom, lying outside ordinary grammatical constraints. The use of ***a** many X* and its alternative *many **a** X* (still in use) is more than 800 years old.

Comment: "wrote very many plays" would be fine.

Comment: It's fine and fairly common. The adjective "great" in "a great many" functions as a pre-determiner modifier that is modifying "many"; it can be replaced by "good" ("A good many plays").

Answer (score 3):

[LINK  Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/a-great-many)

> a great many:   with pl. v.]
>
> an extremely large number (of persons or things)

In this example 'great' is simply making certain that the reader understands that it is more than 'many'.

From Google Dictionary

> great
>
> adjective
>
> 1.of an extent, **amount**, or intensity **considerably above the normal** or average. "the article was of great interest"
>
> synonyms: considerable, substantial, significant, appreciable,
>   special, serious

Comment: All this shows is that it's actually correct - it doesn't really explain why it's correct, which seems to be the question. "A many" is not correct and the OP is trying to understand why it's acceptable here.

Comment: @Catija "Many" combines with "a" to form a complex determinative. The adjective "great" can be replaced by "good", but one or the other is required.The syntax is like that of the complex form "a good few". Why is it correct? Who knows?